# What kind of inductor to choose?

Tags: filter, impedance, ferrite

[image]

Which kind of inductor should I choose if value is the same?

- rolled over a ferrite
- rolled over a plastic
- rolled in air
- rolled in a package *looking like a resistor*

Is it related to specific roles?

For today, I will use a rolled in air one for a low pass filter (RC & LRC), but is it the best choice  (rejecting >~ 100 kHz)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing inductors isn't really delineated so much by visual construction style like you've framed your question with, but rather **core geometry** and **core material**.

I would also note that 2 of these inductors are actually wound around a ferrite core, and their geometries are all very similar as well.  The last one, the 'wound over plastic' inductor has the same geometry as the other 2, but a different core material.  Plastic is magnetically the same as air, so that inductor is actually an air-cored inductor, the plastic is just for mechanical purposes.

These inductors can be broken down like so:

1. The small, resistor-style inductor has dumbbell shaped ferrite core with very thin copper wire wrapped around it.  It will have relatively high resistance and is intended for use in very low current applications, like a signal filter or oscillator or synthesizer.
2. The second smallest inductor is wound over either a bobbin with a ferrite core in the center or possibly the bobbin itself is the core and made of ferrite.  If you cut away the heatshrink, this should be obvious.  This is a medium power inductor that is suitable for currents <1A (this is very very rough ball-park, the actual inductance value will play a large role in the actual current handling capacity).  This is something you might see in a small wall wart as a power supply filter or output filter for a forward converter.
3. The air core inductor will have to be very large indeed to match the inductances of inductors with ferrite or some other magnetic core material.  These are used in high frequency, high **Q** (a measure of efficiency, which is the ratio of an inductor's inductive reactance for a given frequency to its real-numbered resistance).

Core geometry and core material both work to impact an inductor in similar ways.

Core material and core size will determine the **inductance per turns squared vs amp-turns** for an inductor.  Amp turns are the product of the number of turns you have wound around given core and the maximum current you intend to have conducting through that inductor.  If you have 50 turns and 2 amps, that is 100 amp-turns.

As the amp turns increases, the inductance per turns squared, or \$ A_{L} \$ value typically begins to fall.

Larger core geometries result in higher \$ A_{L} \$ that will hold at larger values of amp turns.  Core material will play a roll in this as well, with two identical geometries made from different materials potentially having very different \$ A_{L} \$ and amp turn values.

This also determines **saturation**.  This is the current where the amp turns has increased so much that the \$ A_{L} \$ value is fallen so far that the inductor is now well out of spec for the intended inductance.  The character of the saturation is also largely determined by core material and geometry.

Ferrite saturates like a brick wall.  It is very fast and sudden and you generally want to stay a ways away from the saturation current if possible.

**However**, ferrite can saturate softly as well depending on its geometry.

Magnetism is a circuit, just like current.  The magnetic field is moving through the magnetic core's poles, looping around through the air, then back into the opposite pole.

In a fully enclosed inductor, this field travels entirely through a magnetic core material.  This results in the highest \$ A_{L} \$ value, meaning you get more inductance with fewer turns of wire.

On the flip side, you also get somewhat lower saturation current and amp turns.

If you don't have a fully enclosed core, then part of the field must travel through air, and so the core is partly air, and partly magnetic.  The low permeability of air can be thought of as acting like a series 'resistance' but to magnetic field propagation, which limits the magnetic flux through the magnetic core which ultimately means more amp turns and higher saturation currents.  This also results in a proportional reduction of the \$ A_{L} \$ value.  **However**, since inductance is this value multiplied by turns **squared**, you can actually have your cake and eat it too.  Overall, an air gap will increase the power handling of an inductor for a given inductance, but at the cost of more copper (you need more turns and more wire to get the same inductance).

The other aspect here is core losses.  This is highly dependent on material.  Ferrite has low losses up to a certain frequency (but where this boundary is depends on *which* ferrite, and yes, there are many kinds).  Other materials like iron powder have higher losses but perform better at low frequencies and extremely high frequencies where ferrite stops being effective.

Finally, air cored inductors have the highest Q factors because they don't saturate as there is no core to saturate in the first place.  There likewise is no core for core losses to occur in.  But you need a truly tremendous number of turns and these inductors can get very very large even for relatively small inductance values.  They also will have their fields extend out the furthest rather than concentrating in a magnetic core, so they can couple into other nearby conductors or pick up noise if you're not careful.